# How can I best represent a cartesian product of some fixed dimension?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, cartesian-product

*This question was severely rewritten as per suggestion from @leftaroundabout. An earlier version may be seen in the edit history.*

Haskell is famous for the fact that it facilitates thought, allowing more direct encoding of mathematical abstractions. Cartesian product is a very basic mental object many are familiar with since the very childhood. Yet, there is barely a type for it in Haskell. I think I need one, to enable my thinking to flow, if nothing else. (Although this post is actually inspired by some down-to-earth code I have at hand.) Let us then form a common understanding of what this Cartesian thing (I'll be calling it just *Cartesian* for short) is.

Given a sequence of length `d :: Int` of collections (e.g. `[[1,2], ['a', 'b']]`), I'd like to have all the combinations of their elements at short reach. That means operating on them as though they were in a usual Functor, Foldable, Traversable, Monoid, and so on. Indeed, we may represent any Cartesian as a suitably nested list of tuples:

```
type Lattice = [[(x, y)]]

type WeightedLattice = [[(x, y, w)]]

zipWith2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> [[a]] -> [[b]] -> [[c]]
zipWith2 f = zipWith (zipWith f)

fmap2 :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> g (f a) -> g (f b)
fmap2 = fmap . fmap

sequence2 :: (Traversable s, Traversable t, Monad m) => t (s (m a)) -> m (t (s a))
sequence2 = sequence . fmap sequence
```

Similar constructions can be writ out by hand for any depth of nesting.

We now introduce a distinction between *a* Cartesian and the *initial* Cartesian:

- An n-dimensional Cartesian is constructed from a heterogeneous sequence of collections by taking one element from each collection and combining them, orderly, with a suitably typed function. This, a Cartesian of signature [Int, Char, Bool] may be formed by a function such as:

  ```
  f :: Int -> Char -> Bool -> Either Char Int
  f i c b = if b then Left c else Right i
  ```
- The initial Cartesian is formed with the tuple constructor of matching arity:

  ```
  initial :: Int -> Char -> Bool -> (Int, Char, Bool)
  initial = (,,)
  ```

It is easy to see that we may convert the initial Cartesian, represented as a nested list, to any other Cartesian of the like nesting depth, with a function akin to:

```
    (fmap . ... . fmap) (uncurryN f)
```

However, we may not always come back; indeed, would be hard to recover the right `Char` from a `Right 3`. So, the initial Cartesian can be used in place of any particular Cartesian, but not always the other way around.

As an example, we can use the `Lattice` type defined above to visualize a field, computing its values for some regularly distributed points in space. We would do it with a function that assigns to coordinates a value. There may be any number of such functions, describing different fields in the same points, to each corresponding a Lattice of like dimensions. But there will only be one initial Lattice that contains nothing but coordinates.

However, our nested list encoding has its drawbacks. Besides inducing the ennuy of spelling out all the necessary functions for every next dimension, it is insecure: there is nothing to save you from mistaking an 128 x 64 matrix with a 64 x 128 one and zipping them together, ending up with a 64 x 64 one instead; the order of things in the tuple may or may not correspond to the order of list nesting. On the other hand, the type system works hard against you, not allowing things like `foldr (.) id [replicate d concat]` that could have saved some pain. Not haskelly at all.

But the deepest source of disappointment with this system is that it does not support in any obvious way the very fundamental intuition of the Cartesian: its Monoid instance. It's a property that allows us to think of a point as having not one, not some, but any number `p` of properties, easily adding, combining or throwing them away -- like elements of a list, indeed. Being nailed to a certain depth of nesting and a certain tuple arity is having your wings cut. That Cartesian product is a Monoid in the category of **Set** is a basic fact from category theory, but can we define a Monoid over arbirarily nested lists of arbitrarily typed tuples?

So, the challenge of writing a *Cartesian done right* involves such goals as:

- Any dimension. A list, a matrix, and any other finite-dimensional space should have like interface. Some selection of the usual `Data.List` functions should be implementable.
- Type safety. That is, having the types and the dimensions of a given Cartesian encoded in the type system. For example, if I form a space like `[1..3] x ['a', 'b']`, and another like `[1,2] x ['a'..'c']`, they should have distinct readable type, and not zip together.
- As the Cartesian is determined by the selection of the dimensions, any two Cartesians may be combined just as the lists of their dimensions. For example:

  ```
  Cartesian [[1..3], ['a', 'b']] <> Cartesian [[True, False]]
  ```

  -- should be the same thing as:

  ```
  Cartesian [[1..3], ['a', 'b'], [True, False]]
  ```

  -- Just the same as their generating lists would.
- There should be some notion of the initial Cartesian and the decorations placed over it, so that the coordinates of points are never lost unless the loss is forced. For example, the coordinates of the points of a `Lattice` should be stored separately of the derived properties of the field it describes. We may then, say, obtain a superposition of fields if the Lattices describing them "match".
- The initial Cartesian should be a Monoid.

I sketched some poor thing of a type that's at least somewhat usable and I will post it as an answer in a moment, but for most of the above points I'm at loss. It must take some type trickery. I appreciate any ideas on how to make it.

Comment: Would an instance if [`IArray`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Array-IArray.html#t:IArray) work for you? You can choose its index ([`Ix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Ix.html#t:Ix)) to be a tuple, but as arrays are stored linearly, you have simple `Traversable` etc. instances for them.

Comment: @PetrPudlák I'm thinking of using exactly an array, decorated with dimensions of the input. If that's the best that can be done...

Comment: Forgive me a possibly really stupid question, but what do you mean by a "cortege"? `[[1,2], ['a', 'b']]` doesn't seem to compile in Haskell? (I'm asking because I have a solution in Scala for a similar problem, and I wonder whether it could be useful in Haskell, but I'm not sure whether I understand correctly what you want.)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Whoops, looks like [this term](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) is not in use in English. What I meant is a totally ordered collection. I will edit it to "sequence". In English, the corresponding term is, actually, *tuple*, which is exactly what I was trying to emphasize against. Such things can be represented in Haskell using a [heterogenous collection](https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections), but it has very boring properties.

Comment: This seems to be an interesting question, but I don't find it easy to understand what it's about precisely. Could you add some more code/pseudocode/pseudo-signatures? In particular, what's the relation to tuples – what would be the closest you could get with them, and why is this not satisfying for you?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I added two paragraphs of dreams, is it helpful?

Comment: Yeah, but I still find it too handwaved to answer this. And I still don't see why tuples don't fit the bill. — If you think this would be easy with duck typing, why not add one concrete Python example?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'll think about it and edit further tomorrow then.

Comment: This sounds very much like a (fairly famous I think) paper, whose title I can't remember, about constructing an extensible expression type using typeclasses and type combinators.  Basically, it's a model of an open coproduct.  You could do the same thing, but instead construct an open product.  I hope somebody else here can help me with the name of the paper

Comment: Ah, here it is, [Data Types A La Carte](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~W.Swierstra/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf).  I think you can use analogous techniques to solve your problem.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid suggestion but if all you want is to go from some lists to lists of tuples and you have a fixed number of each you can use applicative stuff: `f = liftA2 (,)` then `f [1,2] [T, F]` is `[(1,T),(1,F),(2,T),(2,F)]` and you can also do eg `liftA3 (,,)`. Obviously this doesn’t work if you want to do this with arbitrary `d`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I redid it from scratch; is it any better now?

Comment: Definitely better. What I don't understand yet – do you actually want to enforce that the values form a “rectangular grid” (i.e., that in a `Cartesian a b` structure, there exists exactly the same number of `b` values for each `a` value, vice versa)? In that case `fmap` seems very dubious, since you can easily destroy that property by passing in a harmless-looking function. If not, then what should be the semantics of the monoid operation? Some examples would be useful.

Comment: @Kindaro Just some nitpicking on nomenclature ;) : "Cartesian is monoid" sounds weird. You could say: `Sets` is a monoidal category with the cartesian product, but then you have to deal with the coherence somehow (you seem to want to "flatten" everything immediately and not distinguish between `(A x B) x C` and `A x (B x C)`). It's somewhat mysterious to me what the "initial Cartesian" is supposed to be. `Sets` has one initial object: the empty set, it is not a monoid because it's empty, and therefore lacks an identity element.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think it would be great if the rectangularity was preserved. I don't really get how you plan to destroy it, though; I thought `fmap` would not change the number of elements? I hope we can simply provide an abstract type to the user, and prove that all internall functions preserve rectangulalrity, rather than type-enforcing it.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I'm not sure I understand the part about coherence.

Comment: @Kindaro but `fmap` can easily change what it would _mean_ to be rectangular. For a literal example, you could start with a 2D rectangular grid of float numbers and perform a coordinate rotation by 45°. The result isn't rectangular WRT to the new coordinate system. Or, simply consider `fmap (\x -> (x,x))` on a 1D int grid. The result is diagonal instead of rectangular.

Answer (score 4):

The question is fairly vague, but it looks like you might be interested in `vinyl`-style records. My definitions are a bit different from `vinyl` proper; use what you like.

```
{-# language DataKinds, PolyKinds, TypeOperators, GADTs #-}
module Cart where
import Data.Kind (Type)
import Data.Functor.Identity

infixr 4 :<
data Rec :: [k] -> (k -> Type) -> Type where
  Nil :: Rec '[] f
  (:<) :: f a -> Rec as f -> Rec (a ': as) f

newtype HList xs = HList (Rec xs Identity)

prod :: Rec as [] -> [HList as]
prod = map HList . go
  where
    go :: Rec as [] -> [Rec as Identity]
    go Nil = [Nil]
    go (xs :< xss) = [ Identity x :< r | x <- xs, r <- go xss]
```

With appropriate `Show` instances (straightforward but a bit annoying), you'll get something like

```
> prod $ [3,4,5] :< ["hello", "goodbye"] :< ['x'] :< Nil

[ H[3,"hello",'x'], H[3,"goodbye",'x'], H[4,"hello",'x']
, H[4,"goodbye",'x'], H[5,"hello",'x'], H[5,"goodbye",'x'] ]
```

This version of `prod` is perhaps a tad too specific, since it only works with `Identity` and lists. Here's a straightforward generalization, where the traversal function "splits" the base functor of the `Rec` and we use an arbitrary `Applicative` rather than just `[]`:

```
class Trav (t :: (k -> Type) -> Type) where
  trav :: Applicative g => (forall a. f a -> g (h a)) -> t f -> g (t h)

instance Trav (Rec as) where
  trav f Nil = pure Nil
  trav f (xs :< xss) = (:<) <$> f xs <*> trav f xss
```

This is just analogous to [`Data.Vinyl.rtraverse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl-0.7.0/docs/Data-Vinyl-Core.html#v:rtraverse), as I finally bumbled my way into recognizing.

---

Records of this sort don't form a `Monoid`, because `mappend` couldn't be typed. But you can certainly append them:

```
type family (++) xs ys where
  '[] ++ ys = ys
  (x ': xs) ++ ys = x ': xs ++ ys

(><) :: Rec xs f -> Rec ys f -> Rec (xs ++ ys) f
Nil >< ys = ys
(x :< xs) >< ys = x :< (xs >< ys)
```

This behaves well. In particular, you can append the records and then traverse them, or traverse them and then append the results.

```
trav f (xs >< ys) = (><) <$> trav f xs <*> trav f ys
```

---

You can also rearrange them in principled ways (analogous to your bubble device). The type

```
forall f k (as :: [k]) (bs :: [k]). Rec as f -> Rec bs f
```

can be given to any function that rearranges a `Rec` without caring what's in it.

---

Since you mention mapping:

```
class Functor1 (t :: (k -> Type) -> Type) where
  map1 :: (forall x. f x -> g x) -> t f -> t g

instance Functor1 (Rec as) where
  map1 f = runIdentity . trav (\x -> Identity (f x))
```

Zipping also works:

```
rzip :: (forall x. f x -> g x -> h x)
     -> Rec as f -> Rec as g -> Rec as h
rzip f Nil Nil = Nil
rzip f (x :< xs) (y :< ys) = f x y :< rzip f xs ys
```

Comment: I remade the question; is it less vague now?

Comment: @Kindaro, no, I'm still pretty lost.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the pain may be taken away by a type like this one:

```
type A e = Array Int e

data Cartesian v = Cartesian
    { _dimensions :: [Int]
    , _values :: A v
    } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

-- # Some helper functions.

autoListArray :: [a] -> A a
autoListArray xs = listArray (0, pred (length xs)) xs

-- | Get elements of an array such that they all belong to the
--   congruence class c modulo n.
getByCongruentIndices :: Int -> Int -> A v -> [v]
getByCongruentIndices n c arr =
    let (low, high) = bounds arr
    in  (arr !) <$> [low + c, low + c + n.. high]

arr :: [v] -> A v
arr = autoListArray

unarr :: A v -> [v]
unarr = elems

congr :: Int -> Int -> A v -> [v]
congr = getByCongruentIndices

congr0 :: Int -> A v -> [v]
congr0 n = congr n 0
```

I will now go checking boxes about it.

- Functor, Foldable, Traversable: Magically derivable out of the box.
- Creating: You may create any Cartesian you wish by incrementally growing a `uni` with `cons`.

  ```
  -- | Consruct a uni-dimensional Cartesian.
  uni :: [v] -> Cartesian v
  uni vs = Cartesian { _dimensions = [length vs], _values = arr vs }

  -- | Dimension increment.
  cons :: (u -> v -> w) -> [u] -> Cartesian v -> Cartesian w
  cons f xs Cartesian{..} = Cartesian
      { _dimensions = length xs: _dimensions
      , _values = arr [ x `f` y | x <- xs, y <- unarr _values ]
      }
  ```
- Destroying: You may peel off layers of a Cartesian with `uncons`.

  ```
  -- | Dimension decrement.
  uncons :: (u -> (v, w)) -> Cartesian u -> Maybe ([v], Cartesian w)
  uncons _ Cartesian { _dimensions = [] } = Nothing
  uncons f Cartesian { _dimensions = (_: ds), _values = xs } =
      let ys = fmap (fst . f) . congr0 (product ds) $ xs
          zs = fmap (snd . f) . take (product ds) . unarr $ xs
      in  Just (ys, Cartesian { _dimensions = ds, _values = arr zs })
  ```
- Transpositions: You may change the order of dimensions with the `(↑)`
  *bubble* device. I don't have a proof, but I'm next to certain you can obtain any transposition you wish. In particular, `(↑) x 1` is equivalent to `Data.List.traverse`.

  ```
  -- | Bubble: apply a cycle from 0 to (i - 1) to the dimensions. That is, make the i-th dimension 
  --   the first. I believe bubbles to be the generators of the symmetric group.
  (↑) :: Cartesian u -> Int -> Cartesian u
  Cartesian{..} ↑ i =
      let d  = product . drop i $ _dimensions
          ds = take i _dimensions ++ drop (succ i) _dimensions  -- Delete the i-th.
      in  Cartesian
              { _dimensions = ds
              , _values = arr . concat $ ($ _values) <$> (congr d <$> [0..pred d])
              }
  ```
- `cons`, `uncons` and `(↑)` allow you to slice and combine again any two Cartesians, or parts thereof. But there is also a way to combine Cartesians directly:

  ```
  appendWith :: (u -> v -> w) -> Cartesian u -> Cartesian v -> Cartesian w
  appendWith f x y = Cartesian { _dimensions = _dimensions x ++ _dimensions y
                               , _values = arr [ x `f` y | x <- unarr (_values x), y <- unarr (_values y) ]
                               }
  ```
- You can also zip things:

  ```
  glue f x y | _dimensions x == _dimensions y
                  = Cartesian
                      { _dimensions = _dimensions x
                      , _values = arr $ zipWith f (unarr $ _values x) (unarr $ _values y)
                      }
             | otherwise = undefined
  ```

On the downside of this, you have to explicitly provide a binary function that could combine the types you have in your Cartesians, everywhere. This would usually be a tuple constructor, but you are not limited to it.

I had trouble defining an instance of Monoid, particularly the `mempty` part, and the *initial* thing is not even near here.